# Why do we have to divide strain engineering components to use them in the strain tensor?

Tags: stress-strain, invariants

I understand the reason of dividing them is in order to correctly perform coordinate transformations on strain tensors.

But it feels to me as if we are tricking ourselves. Strain tensor should naturally be invariant under coordinate transformations without the need to divide its shear engineering components. Just the same with stress tensor where no division takes place when using its components in mathematical operations.

Comment: What do you mean by "divide strain engineering components"? Can you give an example? Are you referring to the definition of strain $\varepsilon_{ij}=\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}$?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the physical meaning of the strain tensor shouldn't depend on the coordinates.  But there's a fascinating mathematical fact that means that the further decomposition of the strain tensor is *also* physically meaningful:  the notion of *irreducible subspaces*.

Let's imagine that we write out the "derivatives matrix" for a material's strain:
$$
D_{ij} = \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}.
$$
The derivatives matrix can then be decomposed into three parts:
$$
D_{ij} = e \delta_{ij} + A_{ij} + E_{ij}
$$
where
$$
e = \frac{1}{3} \,\mathrm{tr}\, D  \qquad A_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} (D_{ij} - D_{ji}) \qquad E_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} (D_{ij} + D_{ji}) - e \delta_{ij}
$$

On its face, this appears to depend on the coordinates we chose, and so it doesn't seem like it would be physically meaningful.  But what's kind of remarkable is that this decomposition is respected by coordinate transformations, in the following sense.  Suppose we change to another set of coordinates and write out the derivatives matrix $D'_{ij}$ in terms of these coordinates.  The components of $D'$ in these new coordinates will be linear combinations of the components of $D$, according to the tensor transformation rules.

We could then do the same decomposition as above to define $e'$, $A'_{ij}$, and $E'_{ij}$ in these new coordinates.  Since $D$ is a mixture of $e$, $A$, and $E$, and similarly for $D'$, $e'$, $A'$ and $E'$, we might expect that the new $e'$ would depend on all three of $e$, $A$, and $E$, as would $A'$ and $E'$.  But what's remarkable is that the new $e'$ depends *only* on $e$ (not $A$ or $E$—in fact, $e' = e$);  the new $A'$ depends *only* on $A$ (not $e$ or $E$);  and the new $E'$ depends *only* on $E$ (not $e$ or $A$.)

In other words, while coordinate transformations "mix together" the components of $D$, they do so in such a way that the "$e$ part", the "$A$ part", and the "$E$ part" don't mix with each other.  These non-mixing "parts" are called *irreducible subspaces* of the "space" of all possible derivative matrices.  Since they don't mix with each other under coordinate transformations, their definition is in some sense independent of the coordinates, and so they're physically meaningful after all.

Concerning the stress tensor, we can certainly do this same decomposition on that one as well.  In fact, for the stress tensor $\sigma_{ij}$, the antisymmetric part (corresponding to $A_{ij}$ above) is automatically zero, since the stress tensor is symmetric:
$$
\sigma_{ij} = \pi \delta_{ij} + s_{ij}
$$
where $\pi \delta_{ij}$ is the [*mean stress tensor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor) and $s_{ij}$ is the *stress deviator tensor*.  For an isotropic medium, Hooke's Law then requires that $\pi$ is proportional to $e$ (and is independent of $E$), while $s_{ij}$ is proportional to only $E_{ij}$.  Again, in this instance, there's no "mixing" between the different "parts".  This means that for isotropic media, we can talk meaningfully about a "bulk modulus" and a "strain modulus" without worrying that (for example) an isotropic stress would lead to an shear strain, or vice versa.